# UFT Automation goes to a different page

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Have you ever seen, that automation scripts using UFT goes to a different page than when you do the flow manualy, I had try descriptive programing, xpath, inside object, FireEvent to click on the continue button before that different page, but nothing works for me.

Comment: You're going to have to be a BIT more specific in describing the problem.  Where are you expecting the automation to go to?  Where does it go to?  Share the code you are using in case there's something in there that's incorrect.  You gotta help us to help you...

Comment: Yeah, Ditto:Dave.  I haven't seen this problem before, but I suspect you might have a situation where you have a page with a button or link that is sitting on top of, or near enough to another link that goes to the different page, and when you click it manually, you get one button/link, but you have captured/recorded the other button somehow.  I would investigate by firing up the GuiSpy and wave it around until you find the right link...  Maybe even View Source on the page to see if there is another link it could be following.  If that's not it, check with the page devs, it may be intentional.

Comment: Yes, there is a continue button, once I click on it manhually it shows a transaction summary page, but if I use UFT, it goes to a different page, I hace tried 
xpath: Browser("Simple Mobile-EN").Page("Customer Information").WebButton("xpath:=//*[@id=""default_submit_btn""]").Click
fireevent: 'Browser("Simple Mobile-EN").Page("Customer Information").WebButton("Submit").FireEvent ("onclick")

Comment: descriptive programming:  Set objDesc = Description.Create
 objDesc("micclass").value= WebButton
 objDesc("name").value= "Submit"
 set objChild= Browser("Simple Mobile-EN").Page("Customer Information").ChildObjects(objDesc)
 objChild(0).Click
 objChild.Count
 set objChild =  nothing

Comment: Have you tried clicking on object with mouse events? E.g `Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")=2` then  `Browser("Simple Mobile-EN").Page("Customer Information").WebButton("Submit").Click` then `Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")=1`

Comment: thanks Victor, I tried but it didn't work neither, I am trying to activate a phone, for that, i need to provide a PIN and after that, create an account, it goes perfect until create the account, once I click on continue it goes to the page where is asking for the PIN again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are events that trigger in a page when certain choices are made. I cam across an issue in a CRM app where when I was selecting an item from a dropdown box, an event was triggered. What I found was that just by asking QTP to select a value from the dropdown field did not trigger the event. I had to use 'Mouse Relay' to trigger the event. I suspect you have something on your page that is not being triggered but without more information, its hard to tell